# The "from" property in the Compose Outlook mode

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365api

Do you plan to add access to the "From" property of a Message Object in the Compose Outlook mode, or would it be possible to provide it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need from the "from" property in Compose mode, you can use Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.

Since you are in Compose mode, the "from" (or sender) is the current mailbox, so calling the userProfile property will give you a UserProfile object. This object gives you access to the following:

- displayName
- emailAddress
- timeZone

Details : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161126.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but there is one thing about userProfile. It always represents the account that is currently logged in, while you can manually  change the From field of a given email to any allowed account/email address.

Comment: When you change the "from" field manually, you can do two things:

1 - select any of the logged-in accounts in the Outlook profile, or
2 - type in a random e-mail address and "link" it to any of the logged-in accounts in the Outlook profile using the "Send Using" field.

So when you call Office.context.mailbox.userProfile, you get information about the right account in the Outlook profile.

Are you saying that you just want the value of the random e-mail address from step 2?